# Django select_related optimization

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-queryset

I looked at the queries that Django runs for a query like:

```
Model.objects.select_related('foo').filter(...)
```

And noticed that it looked like:

```
    {
    u'time':u'0.056',
    u'sql':u'SELECT 
        "model"."id",
        "model"."foo_id",
        <more model fields>
        "foo"."id",
        "foo"."bar_id",
        <more foo fields>
    FROM "model" 
    INNER JOIN "foo" ON ("model"."foo_id" = "foo"."id") WHERE <filter>
  },
  {
    u'time':u'0.003',
    u'sql':u'SELECT 
        "bar"."id",
        <other fields>
    FROM "bar" WHERE "bar"."id" = 6'
  },
  {
    u'time':u'0.003',
    u'sql':u'SELECT 
        "bar"."id",
        <other fields>
    FROM "bar" WHERE "bar"."id" = 6'
  }
  ... many many more
```

Meaning that it generated **loads** of additional queries for the related ForeignKeys.

I have two problems with this:

1. I asked for related **foo** and received **bar** as well.

*Can I limit the 'depth' related goes into?*

2. Most of the **bar** (in other cases even **foo**) are pointing to the same object.

*Can I somehow tell Django that results are 'sparse' and to create a set of IDs first, and query only those?*

Comment: That `select_related` query will not cause Django to fetch the `bars` as well. My guess is that you are using `model.foo.bar` in your view or template. You might want to do `select_related('foo', 'foo__bar')` to prevent a query for every bar.

Comment: I did a reset queries before the DB access and printed the queries immediately after, so I am pretty sure all sub-queries are a result of that one command I issued. I would actually like to **not** pull foo__bar as I am not going to need it in the view.

Comment: As I said before, the queryset will not cause Django to fetch the `bars`. If the model's `__str__` (or `__unicode__`) methods use `self.foo.bar`, then printing the queryset could be that causing the queries. Without seeing your code and how you are testing, I don't have any other suggestions to help you debug.